# How to fade a widget's color, text and icon to a different page while the hero animation is also occurring?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I wish to animate a button between two pages. The button's color, text, icon, and screen position will all be changing. I wish to do a cross fade between the color, text, and icon while the button's position is also moving at the same time (and also in the reverse direction).

Essentially, I wish to combine an AnimatedCrossFade with a Hero.

How can I do this?

Currently, the position is changing over time as expected, and the button is also changing styles. However, the style (color, text, icon) is changing immediately as soon as I press the button - it is not fading between the two over time.

Comment: Hero's flightShuttleBuilder always defaults the context of the Widget it is going to be (toHeroContext.Widget). You can change the flightShuttleBuilder to incorporate both the fromHeroContext.widget and the toHeroContext.widget and the separately turn the child into any Transition widget you like calling ModalRoute.of(context).animation and ...secondaryAnimation. But it's a pain. I was also after a simple solution.